# How to copy methods signatures from one class to a file?

Tags: java, class, methods, copy

I have a Java class that contains all my methods that are reusable in other parts of a framework. There are lots of them. I cannot do much about it because of company policy.

I would like to copy all lines from that class that starts with "public" to a file or another class. Just to have methods signatures for easier search for specific functionality. These methods are being added, removed overtime so maybe a method to copy all of them which can be manually started when I need it? Maybe regular expressions can help but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Document the methods directly inside the class and extract the signatures with javadoc?

Comment: java or reflection will give you a way to generate this you want to generate this file when you want?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca has provided the best approach for this. In fact, I hope he can expand that into an answer. As to the answer / comment regarding reflection. While this might seem to answer the question, it is overkill. See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) (spoiler: yes it is, if there is a better approach altogether).

Comment: @AndrewThompson done as requested

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javadoc` to generate the documentation for you, provided that you add javadoc comments to your method.

So for example, suppose your class has a `User getUser(int id)` method. Also suppose your class is in package `com.example.myproject`. Just before the method definition you should put something like this

```
/**
 * Returns a user given an id
 *
 * @param  id   the id the User has on database
 * @return      An instance of <code>User</code> corresponding to the given id
 */
 public User getUser(int userId) {
```

Notice that the comment starts with `/**` and not with `/*`.

Once you've done that you can invoke `javadoc` to generate the documentation html for your package.

```
javadoc com.example.yourproject
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/javadoc/javadoc.html#GUID-7A344353-3BBF-45C4-8B28-15025DDCC643) is the manual for `javadoc` with further instructions if you need to do anything fancier. And [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) are some suggestions on how to best write your documentation (dated, but still good).

Answer (score 0):

By reflection you can do something like :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReflectionCode {
    public static String reflect(Class<?> classToRead) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Method clas : classToRead.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(clas.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " " +                                    
                clas.getName() + "(" + String.join(",", //
                    Arrays.stream(clas.getParameters())//
                        .map(ReflectionCode::parameterToString)//
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                + ")");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String parameterToString(Parameter p) {
        return p.getType().getSimpleName() + " " + p.getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reflect(ReflectionCode.class));
    }
}
```